# Determine if Json results is object or array

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am using .net web api to get json and return it to the front end for angular. The json can be either an object or an array. My code currently only works for the array not the object. I need to find a way to tryparse or determine if the contents are an object or array.

Here is my code

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
    {
        string singleFilePath = String.Format("{0}/../Data/phones/{1}.json", AssemblyDirectory, id);
        List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();
        Phone phone = new Phone();
        JsonSerializer serailizer = new JsonSerializer();

        using (StreamReader json = File.OpenText(singleFilePath))
        {
            using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(json))
            {
                //if array do this
                phones = serailizer.Deserialize<List<Phone>>(reader);
                //if object do this
                phone = serailizer.Deserialize<Phone>(reader);
            }
        }

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<List<Phone>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, phones);

        return response;
    }
```

The above may not be best way of doing this. Its just where I am now.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Using [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/), you could do this:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
var token = JToken.Parse(content);

if (token is JArray)
{
    IEnumerable<Phone> phones = token.ToObject<List<Phone>>();
}
else if (token is JObject)
{
    Phone phone = token.ToObject<Phone>();
}
```

Comment: you could just check the first charcter, isArray = content[0] == '['

Comment: @johnny5 Manually parsing when a good lib is available is generally not a good idea. Case in point, you forgot to check for whitespace :) `"   []"` is a valid json array.

Comment: that's why I didn't post it as an answer, because it's a hack but it's note worthy.

Comment: how much overhead is there in creating the jToken, isn't that essentially deserializing it?

Comment: @johnny5 "it's note worthy" - agreed. Yes, creating the JToken is basically deserializing a `string` to `Map<string, object>` (no reflection needed). But the OP was already deserializing it anyway.

Comment: Thanks,  `No Reflection Needed`, that was the answer I was looking for, I ended up doing the same in one of my projects, but in order to get the property names I deseralize to JToken but it's is done recursive, I was worried that I would get the same overhead but it should be okay

Comment: @johnny5 Well, at least in principle, there's no *need* for reflection when deserializing to a Map. Whether or not `Json.NET` uses it for whatever twisted reason, I cannot say - I can't attest to its dark magic :D But yeah, theoretically it should be considerably faster than a full-blown deserialization

Comment: @johnny5 's answer helped me. In my case,  JToken.Parse(content) was throwing exception if it's an array, so checking for [ worked for me

Comment: @KristinaLex AFAIK `JToken.parse(content)` only throws when `content` is not a valid json document at all. I think you should look into that first, figure out why you were given an invalid json doc, and fix that.

Comment: @dcastro I know, it's really weird, if I use JArray.Parse (content), it doesn't throw any error. There's only one item in the array. And I can confirm the json is valid

Comment: @KristinaLex uh, jtoken.parse fails but jarray.parse succeeds? Without knowing more, I'd say it could be a bug in the library, probably worth reporting it.

Answer (score 9):

I found that the accepted solution using [Json.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) is a bit slow for large JSON files.
It appears that the `JToken` API is performing too many memory allocations.
Here is a helper method that uses the `JsonReader` API with the same result:

```
public static List<T> DeserializeSingleOrList<T>(JsonReader jsonReader)
{
    if (jsonReader.Read())
    {
        switch (jsonReader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.StartArray:
                return new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<List<T>>(jsonReader);

            case JsonToken.StartObject:
                var instance = new JsonSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
                return new List<T> { instance };
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unexpected JSON input");
}
```

The usage:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string id)
{
    var filePath = $"{AssemblyDirectory}/../Data/phones/{id}.json";

    using (var json = File.OpenText(filePath))
    using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(json))
    {
        var phones = DeserializeSingleOrList<Phone>(reader);

        return Request.CreateResponse<List<Phone>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, phones);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Asthetically I like the answer @dcastro gave better. But, if you are generating a JToken object, you can also just use the **Type** enum property of the token. It's possibly less expensive then doing an object type comparison, as the **Type** property has already been determined.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JTokenType.htm

```
//...JToken token
if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    IEnumerable<Phone> phones = token.ToObject<List<Phone>>();
}
else if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
{
    Phone phone = token.ToObject<Phone>();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Neither, it's actually a {token.Type}");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .NET Core 3.1, you can use the following check on the `JsonElement` object.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

public void checkJsonElementType(JsonElement element) {
    switch (element.ValueKind)
    {
        case JsonValueKind.Array:
            // it's an array
            // your code in case of array
            break;
        case JsonValueKind.Object:
            // it's an object
            // your code in case of object
            break;
        case JsonValueKind.String:
            // it's an string
            // your code in case of string
            break;
       .
       .
       .
    }
}
```

Allowed values of `JsonValueKind` are `Array, False, Null, Number, Object, String, True, Undefined`