# using ServiceStack.Text: determine JSON is Array, Object or String?

Tags: c#, json, servicestack, json-deserialization, servicestack-text

using JSON.net I could do this as answered in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620381/determine-if-json-results-is-object-or-array)

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
var token = JToken.Parse(content);

if (token is JArray)
{
    IEnumerable<Phone> phones = token.ToObject<List<Phone>>();
}
else if (token is JObject)
{
    Phone phone = token.ToObject<Phone>();
}
```

but is there a way i could do it similarly in ServiceStack.Text library?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);

if (JsonUtils.IsJsArray(content))
{
    IEnumerable<Phone> phones = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<List<Phone>>(json);
}
else if (JsonUtils.IsJsObject(content))
{
    Phone phone = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Phone>(json);
}
```