# How do I change my json so that I can use it to populate a datagridview

Tags: c#, json, datagridview

I'm getting a json that isn't proper for populating a `datagridview` (I think). I have tried to make use of the answers I get by searching but I still haven't managed to solve this problem.

This is how I get my json.

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["apikey"] = "my apikey";
            string destination = @"http://www.";
            var response = client.UploadValues(destination, values);
            string responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
```

And this is what I get back and put into responseString.

```
{"error":"","return":{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value"}}
```

And the final code to populate the `datagridview`.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JsonResult>>(responseString);
dataGridView1b.DataSource = result;
```

When I run this code it ends up with the following error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object 
(e.g. {"name":"value"}) into 
typeSystem.Collections.Generic.List`1[MarkkarteringMonitoring.JsonResult]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'error', line 1, position 9.'
```

However, if I use the code below to change the json in "responseString" everyting works and the datagridview will be populated.

```
responseString = "[{\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\",\"key\":\"value\"}]";
```

So, how can I have my json changed automatically and use it to populate my datagridview.

Comment: have a look at [Determine if Json results is object or array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20620510/2417602)

Comment: @vikscool - Maby this is due to my lack of skill, but I don't see how I can put this to use for my problem.

Comment: as per the error output from `Newtonsoft`, you are trying to deserialize an `Object` into an `Array` which is not possible as per the input source. So, the link that I have given you will help you to identify the `responseString` type, if it is not an array you can deserialize it into an object and then pass it into a new list of `List<JsonResult>` as: `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResult>(responseString);` and then `var resultList = (new List<JsonResult>()).Add(result);` and later use the `resultList` as your datasource.

Comment: @vikscool - I'm trying it out, but I get a red squiggle line under: `var resultList = (new List<JsonResult>()).Add(result);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `Newtonsoft` is trying to tell you is that it cannot cast your `JSON Object` into a `JSON Array`.

As what I can see from your `Json` response is that you are receiving a `JSON` string as:

```
{"error":"","return":{"key":"value","key":"value","key":"value"}}
```

So, there are 2 things happening in you code as of now:

1. The string recieved in the `responseString` is clearly an `Object` and not an `Array`.
2. The Deserializable `JsonResult` properties are at the `return` key in the above **JSON String** (*if I assumed that correct*)..

So, what we can do is parse the string into a `JObject`(*using `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`* extension) and then get the `return` token value in a string and parse it to the `JsonResult` Object/Array as.

```
var jobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseString);
var jsString = jobj["return "].ToString(); //here you have to make sure that the key name is specified correctly.
var token = JToken.Parse(jsString);
//now determine wither the recieved string is an object or an array
if (token is JArray)
{
     var results = token.ToObject<List<JsonResult>>();
     dataGridView1b.DataSource = results;
}
else if (token is JObject)
{
    var result = token.ToObject<JsonResult>();
    var results = new List<JsonResult>();
    results.Add(result);
    dataGridView1b.DataSource = results;
}
```

Comment: It works! I'm so grateful for your help! Thank you very much!