# How to deserialize a json when it some time returns array and some time returns model

Tags: c#, rest, .net-core

We are currently using an external api that returns a json object when there is data and an empty json array when it failed. I am looking for the best way to deserialize the json model that is more robust then checking the string.

Currently we are reading the json as a string to see if it contains the empty array and if it does not deserialize into a model.

Empty array

```
"data_field":[]
```

Data Object

```
"data_field":{
"part_one":1,
"part_two":2,
}
```

Comment: so you want to determine if JSON contains object or array after deserialization ?? if i understand ?

Comment: Yeah like i said we parse the json to a string first to check for the Empty array before deserialize and i was looking for a more robust way of checking

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if Json results is object or array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620381/determine-if-json-results-is-object-or-array)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Class like [**this**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3T1v0g):

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Test(JToken.Parse("{}")); // empty object
        Test(JToken.Parse("[]")); // empty array
        Test(JToken.Parse("\"\"")); // empty string
        Test(JToken.Parse("null")); // null value
    }

    private static void Test(JToken token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type: " + token.Type.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Token: " + token.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("IsEmpty1: " + token.IsNullOrEmpty().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("IsEmpty2: " + token.IsNullOrEmpty2().ToString());
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(this JToken token)
    {
        return (token == null) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Array && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && !token.HasValues) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.String && token.ToString() == String.Empty) ||
               (token.Type == JTokenType.Null);
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty2(this JToken token)
    {
        return token == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: explain why voting down